# Trying to run this function in the python console of Pycharm but no matter where I put the return function I keep getting an error

Tags: python, return, conv-neural-network

```
x = []
for l in model.layers:
    for w in l.weights:
        x.append(w)
return x[-1]
```

I indented the return function by 1 space and then two but whenever I run the entire code block in the python console I keep getting the error

```
File "<input>", line 5
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: As the error says, that doesn't appear to be in a function. Is there a `def` line you're missing? You need to be inside a function to `return` from one.

Answer (score 0):

seems you are creating a function with all code inside that function. You should do that as follows;

```
def your_func():
    x = []
    for l in model.layers:
    for w in l.weights:
        x.append(w)
    return x[-1]
```

And in python four spaces are required for proper indentation not one or two.